# Why is longitude also written as B and latitude as k?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google-earth, latitude-longitude

Why is longitude also written as B and latitude as k?

I see that abbreviation when working with Google maps API.

Comment: Huh. I've seen L (Lange) and B (Breite) for longitude and latitude, respectively. That's using the German names. I have not seen B and k. Can you post a link showing the usage?

Comment: Following is an excerpt of the reply when I query Google Map system, @mkennedy, you might not be familiar with the domain I am working in, so, just understand this as some kind of computer language used to exchange information. I believe k & B here are just randomly chosen, a personal decision.
    


"formatted_address":"35 Tô Hiệu, Hiệp Tân, Tan Phu District, Ho Chi Minh, Vietnam",
    "geometry":{
        "location":{
            "k":10.7687982,
            "B":106.62689030000001
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks! When I use Google to translate latitude into Vietnamese, I get vĩ độ and longitude is kinh độ so perhaps latitude sometimes uses b rather than v? That is, I think they're using the first initial from the Vietnamese names.